# Create log file to track data merges

Tags: r

I have a long R model, which includes numerous merge and join operations between different data sets. To be able to make sure that this does not lead to any errors (e.g., inflated data sets due to non-unique identifiers), I maintain a merge tracker, which I coded as follows:

```
merge <- "dat1+dat2=dat1"
count <-  nrow(dat1)
check_t1 <- data.frame(merge, count)
dat1 <- join(dat1, dat2, by = "id1", type = "left")
count <- nrow(dat1)
check_t2 <- data.frame(merge, count)
checkmerge <- rbind(checkmerge, check_t1, check_t2)
```

This has increasingly inflated the readability and speed of the script. So may question: are there any better ways to create soch log files (e.g., via a function), or how do you handle this in general?

Comment: in the nascent pipe-syntax & dplyr (et al) ops R arena, there's [lumberjack](http://www.markvanderloo.eu/yaRb/2017/06/23/track-changes-in-data-with-the-lumberjack/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function like this which contains a `stopifnot` condition. It'll throw an error if your join inflates your data.frame

```
myfun <- function(df1, df2, id, jtype, msg) {
              require(plyr)
              print(msg)
              M <- join(df1, df2, by = id, type = jtype)
              stopifnot(nrow(df1)==nrow(M))
              return(M)
         }

library(plyr)
myfun(mtcars, mtcars, "cyl", "left", "mtcars, mtcars")
```

Output

```
[1] "mtcars, mtcars"
Error: nrow(df1) == nrow(M) is not TRUE
```